# MVC: Just remember username

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to implement a "remember username" feature in my MVC login controller.  I only want to remember the username; I do NOT want to persist the user's authentication cookie (as the "remember me" code does in the MVC template).

I assume that if the user sets the "remember username" check box to true, the controller just needs to save the username in a cookie.  If a user subsequently hits my login page, I check to see if the cookie is present, and if it is, set the "remember my username" check box and supply the username to the form.  Sounds simple; so why am I having so much trouble finding examples online to validate my approach?

And, are there security implications to saving the username in a cookie?  That's reasonably sensitive information; I assume I want to encrypt it.  Is there any magic baked into ASP.NET that makes it easy to encrypt cookies, or do I need to "roll my own"?

Can someone provide guidance and "best practices" for this oh-so-common scenario?

EDIT:

You gotta love MS documentation (if you can find it).  I tracked down [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) covering pretty much everything you want to know about cookies.  Most of the examples involve saving the username (just as I want to do).  But then, in the section on **Cookies and Security** it says to "never store sensitive data in a cookie, such as user names..."  Sigh...

Comment: Of course, you probably know, this is a feature of most browsers.  But, if I read this correctly, you wish to force this and not be dependent on the browser, right?

Comment: @MikeMarks: Ok, one of us is confused (it may be me).  The browser knows how to recognize a username and supply a matching password to an `<input>` element whose "type=password".  But that has nothing to do with automatically populating the Username `<input>` element if the user selects the "remember me" check box on the form.

Comment: All current browsers can fill in both the username and the password.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little embarrassed...  I visited my production website's login page and, sure enough, my username and password are filled in for me.  I've never noticed that behavior before, probably 'cause I always run the development website on the local machine and something prevents IE from remembering the username in that scenario.  Which raises the obvious question of what's different about running locally that IE doesn't remember my username?  Or is it maybe because I've logged in with more than one username on the local box?

Comment: You can tell a browser to save user name's/password/either or both.  Chrome, specifically, because that's what I use.  But if you want to, via server side, force the web app to remember the username via some sort of "remember user name" check-box, that will ensure all browsers will remember the user name, and not be dependent on specific browser settings.  Now, with that out of the way, cookies, to me, are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the plaintext username in a cookie for the sole purpose of prepopulating a login form is generally accepted practice.  (There are some exceptions: banks, for instance, may wish to mask the username as an extra layer of defense.  But implementing this in a secure fashion is non-trivial - you can't just encrypt the cookie and call it a day.  These are highly specialized scenarios the average developer doesn't have to worry about.)

Just don't trust the data in the cookie.  Don't use it as an actual login cookie, don't write it out to the response unencoded (XSS), and so on.

Comment: Just thinking about the subject of encrypting cookies.  I guess if I set the Secure property on the cookie then the cookie itself isn't encrypted, but it will only be sent via HTTPS, so a bad guy would need physical access to the user's computer to get the cookie data.  (Don't mind me... I'm just coming up to speed on the whole cookie thing.  Ergo, simple questions like this SO post.)

Comment: Bob, ASP.NET has cryptographic APIs available for application developers to use.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx and http://codethinktank.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-aspnet-45-machinekey-class-brings.html for some example usage.

This protects the cookie data from an untrusted user.  It's how we secure the forms authentication cookie so that the user can't tamper with it, for instance.